# Erro SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4004 Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation

Tags: laravel

Estou com o erro acima ao hospedar no servidor linux da Locaweb.
Sistema foi desenvolvido em laravel e o banco sql server 2008.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4004 Unicode data in a Unicode-only
>   collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library
>   (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.

O erro ocorre somente quando hospedo. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Esse erro foi resolvido na trend abaixo, segue o link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414890/mssql-query-issue-in-php-and-querying-text-data

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. O problema é que isso ocorre somente quando hospedo no servidor da locaweb. Com isso, não consigo alterar a versão, ou seja, eu preciso alterar essa versão no servidor de hospedagem e não na minha máquina.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437112/laravel-mssql-aws-rds-general-error-20018-unicode-data

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porém não funcionou. Eu utilizo o modo de autenticação do próprio laravel, então não consigo alterar a consulta sql. Continuo com o problema, infelizmente.

Comment: Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma. Pedi para o responsável pela hospedagem trocar a versão da TDS. Eles alteraram e o erro parou de ocorrer.